# How can I efficiently store content into a different list based on prefix?

Tags: python

As you can in the code below: a lot of lines are repetitive.

Everything is involved around the four keywords `['copy', 'scale', 'add', 'triad']`, is it possible to just write one line of `line.startswith` and `list.append` and somehow dynamically substitute the four keywords at the right place?

The file I am reading has the following format (I made up the numbers):

copy: 1 2 3 4
scale: 1 2 3 4
add: 1 2 3 4
triad: 1 2 3 4

All I care about is the `first column`, which is all the 1s

```
copy_s = []
scale_s =[]
add_s = []
triad_s = []

with open('./a_file') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip().lower()

        if line.startswith('copy'):
            copy_s.append(float(line.split()[1]))
            continue
        elif line.startswith('scale'):
            scale_s.append(float(line.split()[1]))
            continue
        elif line.startswith('add'):
            add_s.append(float(line.split()[1]))
            continue
        elif line.startswith('triad'):
            triad_s.append(float(line.split()[1]))
            continue
```

P.S. Should I ask this type of question in StackOverflow or Code Review?

Comment: Do you really need 4 lists or would a dictionary suffice?

Comment: CodeReview definitely makes more sense for this question.

Comment: @Sayse you are right a dictionary is better

Comment: (That said, changing the question from "How can I improve this code?" to "How can I efficiently store content sorted by prefix?" or such might make it at least appear to be a better fit for SO: It's making a question that isn't just seeking suggestions for *you*, but seeking a best-practices way to accomplish a task other programmers are likely to encounter as well. Our overarching goal is to provide a comprehensive database of Q&A questions reusable by others with similar problems -- hence the old "too localized" close reason for non-reusable questions).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thx for the suggestion, I will change the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a dictionary to store your prefixes and corresponding values:

```
d = {}
with open('./a_file') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip().lower()
        prefix, num = line.split(':')[0], float(line.split()[1])
        d[prefix] = num
```

Use a `collections.OrderedDict` if the order matters.

Answer (score 0):

Define a dynamic variable that chooses which array to actually append to, then change your elif block as follows:

```
    if line.startswith('copy'):
        array = copy_s
    elif line.startswith('scale'):
        array = scale_s
    elif line.startswith('add'):
        array = add_s
    elif line.startswith('triad'):
        array = triad_s
    endif

    array.append(float(line.split()[1]))
```